# PyGreSQL NULLs for integer field

Tags: python, database, pygresql

I am trying to insert some rows into a table which has a field of integers, which can be NULL:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id, priority) VALUES (%(id)d, %(priority)d)", \
            {'id': id, 'priority': priority})
```

The priority variable is either an integer or `None`. This works when priority has an integer value, however, when it is `None` I get the following error:

```
internal error in 'BEGIN': int argument required
```

I notice that for string formatting for Python in general you cannot use `None` as the value of an integer to be formatted - it throws the same error that pgdb is throwing. However, when I change the formatting string to `%(priority)s` the error changes to:

```
internal error in 'BEGIN': unsupported format character 'W' (0x57) at index 60
```

I guess that's because I'm then trying to import a string into an integer field.

How do I import the NULL values?

Comment: One version of pygresql are you using? The release notes claim that something was done about this in version 3.0.

Comment: Also, are you sure that priority is an `int` and not a number within a `str`?

Comment: `pgdb.version` reports '4.0' and `priority` is definitely an integer - it's created using `int(some_str)`

Answer (score 1):

Normally Postgresql performs automatic casting of string values to integer for integer columns. So it is generally safe to use a string formatter like %(priority)s for an integer column provided the string parameter contains an integer or is None.  If the string is set to None then the column will be assigned NULL.